# Java 11 get current Microseconds?

Tags: java

I already read an answer about if it's possible in Java 8 to get the current microseconds and the answer was no, but is it possible now in Java11?

The solution by using System.nanoTime() * 1000 is too inefficient.
Note: The Goal is NOT to get the exact current time in nanoseconds (for example 12:00 PM), obviously that's not working like this.

I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: *not with `System.nanoTime()/1000`* -- What's wrong with this solution? Your question is not clear.

Comment: what @JonathonReinhart said

Comment: `System.nanoTime() / 1000` is _not_ going to give you anything resembling a current time.  The OP is correct: `System.nanoTime()` is nothing like "nanoseconds since the epoch," but "nanoseconds since some undefined but fixed moment."

Comment: The problem is efficiency. The solution with taking the nano secs and dividing them is very inefficient and takes too much processor capacity (not the dividing, more the reading itself).

Comment: @BytePhil: There's _definitely_ not going to be anything that performs better than that.  There _may_ be a solution that's more correct than that, though.

Comment: @BytePhil It is defnitely not inefficient. the time you lose here is probably even less than the time for creating a variable here and there, calling some method over there, ... It is so small that its meaningless to even reason about it. In particular when coding in a VM language. _Microoptimization is the root of all evil_ - as they say for a good reason.

Comment: @Zabuzard not helpful :). When you try to do a very exact scheduler and the processor power is very weak not everything can be done by "calling some method over there"...

Comment: It's usually not possible to make a "very exact scheduler" on most systems.  This sounds like an X-Y Problem.  Can you tell us what you are actually trying to do?  What do you need this scheduler do?

Comment: @BytePhil You would be surprised how many people make their code actually slower than faster by their _educated guesses_. Read about the quirks of VMs and microoptimizations.

Comment: I'm confused; you say you're trying to get a very exact scheduler on a "weak" processor in regular Java. These are incompatible goals.

Answer (score 4):

As before, `Instant.now()` uses the most accurate time source available to the system.  Depending on the system, there may not be anything finer-grained than `System.currentTimeMillis`.

As mentioned in the comments, `System.nanoTime() / 1000` can be used for measuring the time *between* values, but doesn't give you anything like "the current time" -- you can't tell from it, for example, whether or not it's 3:00 PM.

If you need to measure or calculate e.g. the time between events in your program, there is nothing that will do better for you than [`System.nanoTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()).

Comment: Is there any way to use the Instant.now method to get the micro secs directly? Or only through dividing Instant.now().getNano() with 1000?

Comment: Micro seconds since what?

Comment: (`getNano() / 1000` is also not going to do what you want, FYI.)

Comment: At the moment im doing it with System.nanoTime(), but since I only need the microseconds I wanted to get them directly. Is there any method (like the Instant.now()) to get the "currentTime" microseconds (so same as with TimeMillis and Nano but as Microseconds)

Comment: It's important what you're using this for.  Are you using this to get an actual time, like 1:20 PM, Oct 20, 2021, US/Los_Angeles?  Measure the time between two events?  `System.currentTimeMillis` and `System.nanoTime` have _completely different_ use cases.  You haven't described the problem in enough detail for us to tell you the right solution for you.

Comment: I kind of want to use this as a very exact scheduler, so it's important to get the time differences. The goal is NOT to get the current actual-time like 1:20 PM. And as I said, I need microseconds and maybe getting them directly would be more efficient then multiplying the nanoSecs

Comment: There's not going to be anything faster for that use case than `System.nanoTime`, which is also more appropriate for that use case than `System.currentTimeMillis`.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help @Louis Wasserman

Comment: if you want to measure time diff you have to use the nanosecond clock since only that doesnt drift. the other clocks are subject to correction and drifts since they measure current time and are not meant to be used as stopwatch. for example when the clock is corrected by the machine calling a time server.

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69652431/642706) is correct. Here are more thoughts.

## Not real-time

You commented:

> When you try to do a very exact scheduler

Conventional implementations of Java, and conventional computer hardware, are *not* “very exact” along the scale of nanosecond and microsecond that you seemed to be targeting.

For “very exact” scheduling, you would have to use special hardware with special software. Look for the buzzword [*real-time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing), such as [*real-time Java*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java).

## `System.nanoTime()`

You said:

> The solution by using System.nanoTime() * 1000 is too inefficient. Note: The Goal is NOT to get the exact time in nanoseconds

Be aware that `System.nanoTime()` does *not* tell you the current time.

`System.nanoTime()` tells you the *approximate* amount of nanoseconds that have elapsed since some arbitrarily chosen moment. In some implementations of Java, that moment may have been when the JVM was launched, or when the computer was booted, or something else. But you cannot count on that origin, nor should you care about the origin.

Represent elapsed time using [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class.

To capture elapsed time in Java for micro-benchmarking:

```
long start = System.nanoTime() ;
…
Duration elapsed = Duration.between( start , System.nanoTime() ) ;
```

You can interrogate the `Duration` for its parts such as nanoseconds, whole seconds, minutes, and hours.

You said:

> System.nanoTime() * 1000 is too inefficient

You must have meant:

```
( start - System.nanoTime() ) / 1_000
```

… to get a count of elapsed microseconds.

And, no, dividing or multiplying integers is not “inefficient“. If you care about optimizing for integer division operations, you should not be using conventional Java on conventional hardware, as discussed in section above.

## `Instant.now()`

If you want to capture elapsed time as seen by human clocks:

```
Instant start = Instant.now() ;   // May be precise to milliseconds, microseconds, or such depending on your implementation of Java and your host computer hardware clock.
…
Instant end = Instant.now() ;
```

To represent that elapsed time unattached to the timeline, use `Duration`.

```
Duration elapsed = Duration.between( start , end ) ;
```

To represent that elapsed time attached to the timeline, write a class storing a pair of `Instant` objects.

```
record SpanOfTime ( Instant start , Instant end ) {}
```

Or better yet, add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. This library brings classes that add functionality to the built-in *java.time* classes. One of these is [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), with handy comparison methods such as `abuts`, `contains`, `encloses`, `overlaps`, etc.